# REACT form deselect with onChange handler updating state

Tags: reactjs, forms, state, handler, setstate

I am building a calendar with full calendar and elastic ui, I am trying to double bind value in the form and state, however the form will deselect while I type in every letter, so I will have to select the form again to type in another one, other than that the binding is working, do anyone know what's wrong with the code? appreciate you help!

```
class Calendar extends Component {

state = {
    selectInfo: null,
    start_date: null,
    end_date: null,
    title: null
}

render() {

    const AddEventBar = () => {
        
        const AddEventHandler = () => {
            let calendarApi = this.state.selectInfo.view.calendar
                  calendarApi.addEvent({
                    title: this.state.title,
                    id: new Date(),
                    start: this.state.start_date,
                    end: this.state.end_date,
                    allDay: this.state.selectInfo.allDay
                  })
        }
    
        const titleHandler = (event) => {
            this.setState({title: event.target.value})
        }

        const startDateHandler = (event) => {
            this.setState({start_date: event.target.value})
        }
    
        return (
            <EuiFlexGroup>
                <EuiFlexItem>
                    <EuiForm >
                        <EuiFormRow label='Title'>  
                            <EuiFieldText
                                placeholder="Title"
                                value={this.state.title}
                                onChange={titleHandler}
                                aria-label="Use aria labels when no actual label is in use"
                            />
                        </EuiFormRow>
                        <EuiFormRow label='Start Date'>
                            <EuiFieldText
                                placeholder="Start Date"
                                value={this.state.start_date}
                                onChange={startDateHandler}
                                aria-label="Use aria labels when no actual label is in use"
                            />
                        </EuiFormRow>
                        <EuiFormRow label='End Date'>
                            <EuiFieldText
                                placeholder="End Date"
                                value={this.state.end_date}
                                // onChange={}
                                aria-label="Use aria labels when no actual label is in use"
                            />
                        </EuiFormRow>
                        <EuiFormRow>
                            <EuiButton onClick={()=>AddEventHandler()} type='submit'>
                                Add Event
                            </EuiButton>
                        </EuiFormRow>
                    </EuiForm>
                </EuiFlexItem>
            </EuiFlexGroup>
        )
    }

    const handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
        if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
        clickInfo.event.remove()
        }
    }

    const handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
        let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar
        calendarApi.unselect() // clear date selection
        if(selectInfo) {
            this.setState({selectInfo: selectInfo, start_date:selectInfo.startStr, end_date: selectInfo.endStr})
        }
      }
    

    return (
    <EuiFlexGroup direction='row'>
        <EuiFlexItem grow={8}>
            <FullCalendar
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin ]}
            googleCalendarApiKey = {process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}
            events = {{
                googleCalendarId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID
                }}
                headerToolbar={{
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                }}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                selectable={true}
                editable={true}
                expandRows={true}
                select={handleDateSelect}
                eventClick={handleEventClick}
                />
        </EuiFlexItem>
        <EuiFlexItem grow={2}>
            <AddEventBar></AddEventBar>
        </EuiFlexItem>
    </EuiFlexGroup>
    )
}}



export default Calendar
```